# How can I sum of two dict values based on other dict keys?

Tags: python

```
list = [{'amount': 6.0, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Franchise Royalty'}
**{'amount': 1.0, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Advertising'}
{'amount': 5.0, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Advertising'}**
{'amount': 1.3, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '$', 'Charge Code Description': 'Order Processing Charge'}
{'amount': 1.3, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '$', 'Charge Code Description': 'Order Processing Charge'}
{'amount': 6.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2020-01-19 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2023-02-26 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Franchise Royalty'}
{'amount': 6.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2023-02-27 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Franchise Royalty'}
**{'amount': 1.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2023-02-26 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Advertising'}**
{'amount': 1.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2023-02-27 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Advertising'}
**{'amount': 5.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2023-02-26 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Advertising'}**]
```

How can I have a list like this?

```
[{'amount': 6.0, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Franchise Royalty'}
**{'amount': 6.0, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Advertising'}**
{'amount': 1.3, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '$', 'Charge Code Description': 'Order Processing Charge'}
{'amount': 1.3, 'store_id': 1, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '$', 'Charge Code Description': 'Order Processing Charge'}
{'amount': 6.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2020-01-19 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2023-02-26 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Franchise Royalty'}
{'amount': 6.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2023-02-27 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Franchise Royalty'}
{'amount': 1.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2023-02-27 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2040-12-31 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Advertising'}
**{'amount': 6.0, 'store_id': 2, 'Effective Date': Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'), 'Expired Date': Timestamp('2023-02-26 00:00:00'), 'rate type': '%', 'Charge Code Description': 'Advertising'}**]
```

I couldnt find to do summation of values based on condition

Please guide me to right direction,

Thank you

Tried to use collection, counter but I cant add any condition when trying to compare within the same list

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you ask a question. And use correct formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# convert your list of dicts to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(your_list)

# groupby 'store_id', 'Effective Date', 'Expired Date', 'rate type', and 'Charge Code Description', and then sum the 'amount'
df_grouped = df.groupby(['store_id', 'Effective Date', 'Expired Date', 'rate type', 'Charge Code Description'])['amount'].sum().reset_index()

# convert the grouped dataframe back to a list of dicts
new_list = df_grouped.to_dict('records')
```

Try this:)